# Inability to write in mongoDB: Inability to write in mongoDB:

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

***Hi***,when I try to save in the mongoDB no data is saved

I put more code in my app to better report the bug. The question is: In the code that I created to be able to record in the DB, why doesn't it work? What am I doing wrong?

**My model is:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const pacientesSchema = new Schema({
    nombre: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
    },
    propietario: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    fecha: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    telefono: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    hora: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    sintomas: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Paciente', pacientesSchema);
```

**My controller:**

```
>     exports.nuevoCliente = async (req, res, next) => {
>         // console.log(req.body);
>         
>         // Crear Objeto de paciente con datos de req.body
>         const paciente = new Paciente(req.body);
>         try {
>             await paciente.save();
>             res.json({ mensaje : 'El cliente se agregó correctamente'}); 
>             // console.log(paciente);
>             
>         } catch (error) {
>             console.log(error);
>             next();
>         }
>     }
```

With the kind suggestions of **Stennie** and **Kris** I made this change, it doesn't work, what else could I try? ***what am I missing ???***

```
exports.nuevoCliente = async (req, res, next) => {
    // console.log(req.body);

    // Crear Objeto de paciente con datos de req.body
    const paciente = new Paciente(req.body);

    try {
        await paciente.save({
            nombre: req.body.nombre,
            propietario: req.body.propietario,
            fecha: req.body.fecha,
            telefono: req.body.telefono,
            hora: req.body.hora,
            sintomas: req.body.sintomas
        });
        res.json({ mensaje : 'El cliente se agregó correctamente'}); 
        // console.log(paciente);

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        next();
    }
}
```

**My main index:**

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const routes = require('./routes');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Crear el servidor
const app = express();


// Conectar con MongoDB
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/veterinaria', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
});

// Habilitar el body-parser
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

// Habilitar Routing
app.use('/', routes())


// Puerto y Arrancar
app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('Servidor funcionando')
})
```

Thanks everybody

EDIT: Hello everyone, I already have the solution, it was a link failure when connecting compass with Atlas.
The link I used allowed me to connect and create DB and collections, but not to put data in the collection. This was the link that compass offered me:

```
mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0-srtud.mongodb.net/test
```

**and this is the correct code:**

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/?readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl=false
```

It was a beginner's failure not to know that it was not the right link

Thanks to everybody

Comment: Your command line of `mongo log` connects to a local instance of MongoDB and selects the `log` database (which doesn't have any special meaning as far as MongoDB is concerned). You would get the same output just running `mongo`. There is a startup warning that you don't have any authentication enabled and a banner about enabling (optional) free monitoring. Your current question doesn't show any attempt to write data; please edit it to include an example of the write operation you are trying to perform and the resulting error message.

Comment: I have updated the question data

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to add one entry to an existing database, you can do so with

```
db.COLLECTION_NAME.insert({})
```

If you don't know how to add a database or a collection you can find some useful examples here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_insert_document.htm

EDIT:
You need to import your model in your controller first

```js
const Pacientes = require('../models/Pacientes.js');
```

Comment: yes : const Paciente = require('../models/Paciente'); is in my controller